# A hyperreal field is a minimal field such that ...?

Tags: soft-question, nonstandard-analysis

The standard presentation of hyperreals is difficult to understand. One typically motivates the hyperreals by a desire to have a consistent theory of infinitesimal elements, and then introduces the idea of the transfer principle. This is difficult to understand intuitively because most people don't have intuition about which statements can and cannot be expressed as first-order statements.

One might instead wonder whether we can say something like "a hyperreal field is a minimal field that contains $\mathbb{R}$ and an infinitesimal element" but this is false as discussed [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/234477/hyperreal-field-extension). Any actual hyperreal field contains a lot of elements that $\mathbb{R}(\epsilon)$ doesn't. Still, it seems that the motivation behind hyperreal fields is to have a minimal field that contains $\mathbb{R}$, an infinitesimal element, and enough other elements so that we can "do calculus" on this field.

Is there a formalization of this concept that's more intuitive, such as "a hyperreal field is a minimal field $F$ that contains $\mathbb{R}$ and at least one infinitesimal element and supports the following operations: ... (*e.g.*, extensions of certain real-valued functions to $F$) such that the following identities hold ... (*e.g.*, a list of identities that are similar to the ones obeyed by those functions on $\mathbb{R}$)"?

Comment: Is the generality important to you? When trying to explain hyperreals I usually just give the standard ultrapower construction of a hyperreal field (which sort of obviously has the transfer principle) and then could handwave and say "anything where we could do that stuff would suffice".

Comment: @MarkS. It seems to me that the explicit ultrapower construction is useful in order to prove that a field with all the properties we want the hyperreals to have _actually exists_, but my question is more about what properties we do want.

Comment: At minimum, it seems to me we need something like "every function you'd want to do calculus on, even if you haven't thought of it yet or it's not analytic, has a natural extension to the hyperreals" which seems close to the transfer principle already. I'm curious to see what answers people have.